# Running Ruby debugger on Eclipse PDT

Tags: ruby, eclipse, ruby-debug

I am trying to run a ruby debugger in Eclipse. I have not run a ruby debugger before, so I am not sure where to troubleshoot the problem. I am using Eclipse for PHP Developers, Version: Helios Release, Build id: 20100617-1415. I am using Ruby 1.8.6 (2007-09-24 patchlevel 111) [i386-mswin32]).

I installed ruby-debug (v 0.10.4) and set that as the debug engine in eclipse. I selected that as the debugger engine for ruby. I did not know what to put in the path so I set the path to c:\ruby\bin\rdebug.bat (my install path on Windows).  The environment is set to localhost (not sure what that entails, but it was there by default).

I hardcoded the port for the dynamic languages debugger. I did get a connection status window, but it was never successful.

When I try to run a script in debug configuration, I get a dialog error that says "debugger process was unexpectedly terminated". In my console, it says:
*Could not redirect message, cause communication links broken. Message:* [followed by the output of my puts statements].

I've search for a few hours on how to set this up. Maybe it's not typical. If anybody has experience setting this up on Eclipse or NetBeans, I'd appreciate any pointers you can give.

Thanks

Dave

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first question I'd have is whether ruby-debug by itself in command-line mode works.

Comment: The command-line mode doesn't look like something I really want to use, but for the sake of troubleshooting (and understanding how it works), I will try that as soon as I can.

Comment: Yes, I understand that the command-line mode is not something you or others may not want to use. But as you say, it helps troubleshooting. There are fewer things to go wrong and it somewhat narrows where the problem lies.